# Run apachetop from Java

Tags: java, unix

Since I have too many apache log files, I decided to create a java program build the command for me to run the `apachetop`. So I decided to create a index file, where all the apache_log files will be placed.

**apache_logs_index**

```
/opt/lampp/logs/access_log
/opt/lampp/logs/error_log
/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log
/opt/lampp/logs/ssl_request_log
/opt/lampp/logs/mb.domain.com-access_log
/opt/lampp/logs/mb.domain.com-error_log
/opt/lampp/logs/my.domain.com-access_log
/opt/lampp/logs/my.domain.com-error_log
/opt/lampp/logs/op.domain.com-access_log
/opt/lampp/logs/op.domain.com-error_log
```

And I created a java program to build the command for me.

**ApacheTopCall.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ApacheTopCall{

        public static void main(String args[]) {

                String fileName = "apache_logs_index";
                String command = "apachetop";
                command = command + " -d 1";
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                command = command + " -f " + line.trim();
                        }
                        //System.out.println(command);
                        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", command);
                        Process p = pb.start();
                        p.waitFor();
                } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

}
```

Now all I want is to run `apachetop` by itself. I tried to call it using `ProcessBuilder` but `apachetop` is not displaying, instead, it is simply waiting for the process to be quit. When I run my java code, I want the command to be executed and the `apachetop` should be run.

When I am executing the command built by the java code, it is working good. But not with `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to achieve is this, then here is the simple and effective solution:

You also need to make some small changes to your java code as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ApacheTopCall{

        public static void main(String args[]) {

                String fileName = "apache_logs_index";
                String command = "apachetop";
                command = command + " -d 1 -q -l -r -p"; //extra params
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                command = command + " -f " + line.trim();
                        }
                        System.out.println(command); //we are just creating the command for run. The C program actually run the generated command.
                        //ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", command);
                        //Process p = pb.start();
                        //p.waitFor();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

}
```

I created a simple C program `apachetopall.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        FILE *fp = popen("cd /root/scripts/; java ApacheTopCall", "r"); //make sure you cd to the location of your java class.
        char cmd[32768];
        fgets(cmd, 32768, fp);
        system(cmd);
        return 0;
}
```

Compile it and save it as apachetopall with the following command

```
gcc -o apachetopall apachetopall.c
```

Now all you need to do is, execute the binary `apachetopall`. And your goal is achieved.

**How it works**

Instead of asking the java to run the command, we are asking the java to create the command which is needed to be fired. Now the C program runs the java code and gets the command as output and it fires the same command, which goes to the front of the screen.